# Zsh's standard completion works fine, so why do people recommend to load compinit module?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

If I put these lines and nothing else in my `~/.zshrc` I get all the completion features I expected.

```
# For autocompletion with an arrow-key driven interface
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
# report what kind of completion zsh doing
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
# show ls style colours on file completions
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
# report position when autocompleting lists bigger than available screen
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s%p
```

So why do people recommend you load `compinit`?, i.e.

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

# completion  config directives  go here
```

My testing shows it doesn't improve zsh's completion, and it doesn't fix the zsh completion that is broken but works in bash (i.e. curl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The completion system activated by `compinit` *does* improve the basic one. The basic system is for the most part not aware of context, and completes only file names almost everywhere. The “new” completion system activated by `compinit` knows that it should complete options for many commands when the argument starts with `-`, that it should complete commands in `$PATH` (in root's PATH, even) rather than file names after `sudo`, that it should complete host names after `ssh`, etc.

I don't know why you say that the completion for curl is “broken”. Maybe it's because it isn't installed? Older versions of zsh had completion for curl, but newer versions rely on the completion script included in the curl distribution. Check that your curl installation includes `_curl` somewhere under `/usr/local/share/zsh/functions` or `/usr/share/zsh/functions` (some distributions are missing this file).